# Generate INSERT for "image" type in MSSQL (Java)

Tags: java, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I have a database, where one of the table's column is "image" type. I put there encoded pdf file.

My goal is to print in Java Applications Console, INSERT STATEMENT with all data from my table (so to do the same thing as "Generate Script..." does from Management Studio). However, since my "image" column is binary, I don't know how to encode it to put into INSERT statemnent so this statemement would be executable.

Comment: Don't use the image datatype. It has been deprecated for almost 15 years now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 You should be using varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: To the question at hand...it isn't clear what you want.

Comment: I can't for the life of me determine why somebody would think this question is worthy of an upvote.

Comment: It's true - it's not :). Sorry and thanks for pointing out that I would need to redefine my question. Hopefully, now it's more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) SQL function to convert from binary (varbinary) to string (varchar), in order to translate your binary data to and from an string (with its hexadecimal representation).

The convert function has a parameter style, that indicates if the string starts with a 0x character or not. I use the value 2 (no 0x character) on these examples.

From binary to string :

```
select convert(varchar(max), my_image, 2) as my_string_representation
from my_table
```

From string, back to binary :

```
select convert(varbinary(max), my_string_representation, 2) as my_binary_image
from my_table
```

So, in order to build your plain-text insert statement, lets suppose that **convert(varchar(max), my_image, 2)** has returned the '49747A696B...' string on a certain record, then your insert statement for that record would be :

```
insert into my_table (my_id, my_image)
            values (25, convert(varbinary(max), '49747A696B...', 2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, when I've tried to use this I get a problem: Explicit conversion from data type image to varchar(max) is not allowed.

Comment: Yes, as said on some comment, image datatype is obsolete, you should change your field from image to varbinary(max).